# how get customer first name and last name

Tags: c#

I'm wondering how to change this code to get first name and last name. My friend and I develop this code but I need to alter this code.  There is `Customer` class as well where I set their properties.  So looking for suggestion to alter this:

```
//Getting No: Of Customers for user wish to enter data.
do
{
    needToGetInputFromUser = false;
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter customer name");
    customerName = Console.ReadLine();

    if (customerName.Length < 5 || customerName.Length > 20)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid name length, must be between 5 and 20 characters");
        Console.WriteLine("Please try again.");
        Console.WriteLine(" ");

        needToGetInputFromUser = true;
    }
    else
    {
        isUserEnteredValidInputData = true;
    }

} while (needToGetInputFromUser);
//Getting Account number
```

Comment: You've got the code you need right there. That code takes a name and validates it's length. You need to do that for a first and last name.

Comment: @ashwin Nair. got it mate. thanks

Answer (score 1):

My approach is slightly different from everyone else's, Where I ask for first name first, then last name. Here is the `Customer` class:

```
class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; } }
}
```

Basically I create a `Customer` object then set the `FirstName` and `LastName` based on user input individually like so:

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var customer = new Customer();
            customer.FirstName = GetStringValueFromConsole("Customer First Name");
            customer.LastName = GetStringValueFromConsole("Customer Last Name");
            Console.WriteLine("New Customers name: " + customer.FullName);
            Console.WriteLine("Finished");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static string GetStringValueFromConsole(string valueToAskFor)
        {
            var needToGetInputFromUser = false;
            var stringValue = string.Empty;
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter " + valueToAskFor);
                stringValue = Console.ReadLine();
                if (stringValue.Length < 5 || stringValue.Length > 20)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid \"" + valueToAskFor + "\", must be between 5 and 20 characters");
                    Console.WriteLine("Please try again.");
                    Console.WriteLine(" ");
                    needToGetInputFromUser = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    needToGetInputFromUser = false;
                }
            } while (needToGetInputFromUser);
            return stringValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No worries, FYI you may wanna change the lower limit of a name to something like 3 characters, someone with the name of Jim, wouldn't be a valid name.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Customer>  ListOfCustomer = new  List<Customer>  ();
do
{
    needToGetInputFromUser = false;
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter customer name");
    customerName = Console.ReadLine();

    if (customerName.Length < 5 ||   customerName.Length > 20)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid name length, must be between 5 and 20 characters");
        Console.WriteLine("Please try again.");
        Console.WriteLine(" ");

        needToGetInputFromUser = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Customer c = new Customer();
        c.Name =  customerName;
        ListOfCustomer.Add(c);
        isUserEnteredValidInputData = true;
    }

} while (needToGetInputFromUser);

int CustomerCount = ListOfCustomer.Count;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you get a string like:

> Brian Mains

And you want to split by the " " between Brian and Mains, storing it in first/last name in the Customer object right?  I think you are trying to do something like:

```
Customer c = new Customer();

if (customerName.Contains(" ")) {
   var terms = customerName.Split(' ');
   if (terms.Length == 2) {
      c.FirstName = terms[0];
      c.LastName = terms[1];
   }
   else { 
      //TBD
   }
}
```